# Replace 8 characters after finding 3 characters from a string

Tags: c++, c++11

Is it possible in C++ to replace 8 characters after finding 3 characters from a string 
 I tried below

Input:
 txtvar = "This is for Testing Purpose line";

Expected should be output
txtvar = "This is for Testing XXXXXX line";

I tried below

```
std::string::size_type pos; 
while (( pos = txtvar. find ("Testing")) ! = std::string::npos) { 
    txtvar.replace(pos, 9, XXXX); 
}
```

After finding the Testing keyword next to that 9 characters should be replaced to "XXXXXXX"

Please help me on this

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the tour and read through [How do I ask a good question?])(https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can, the string class have methods for that, just look in the documentation for it:

```
//https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string
std::string txtvar {"This is for Testing Purpose line"};
//https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find
auto index {txtvar.find("Purpose")};
std::string t{"XXXXXXX"};
txtvar.replace(index, 7, t);
std::cout << txtvar << std::endl;
```

Comment: I'm getting output for this, but in the find function we should find a string "Testing" and after that only characters should be replaced as XXXXXX. ie, purpose should be replaced

Comment: Got it!
int main() {
std::string txtvar {"This is for Testing Purpose line"};
//https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find
auto index {txtvar.find("Testing")};
std::string t{"XXXXXXX"};
txtvar.replace(index+8, 7, t);
std::cout << txtvar << std::endl;
}

Comment: @Sam You might have noticed that code posted in comments doesn't render in a readable form. If the answer helped to solve your problem, you can mark it as accepted.